# Can fields be reused with a different name per section?

Tags: craft3

I've got a redactor field used on several sections, and category groups. Is there a way to change the displayed name per section in the edit form?

On a category group the field is, 'Category Description', and on products, 'Product Description', but under the hood they're both 'richText'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of these might help (I use the first one):

- https://plugins.craftcms.com/fieldlabels
- https://plugins.craftcms.com/relabel